# Can't debug ASP.NET Core code - code type is 'x64' so debugger does not load symbols for managed code

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis, remote-debugging

I have several ASP.NET Core websites (.NET 7), and each of them run fine on both my local dev computer's IIS and remote server's IIS.

When I debug a website, I use Visual Studio's `Attach to process` dialog. In that dialog, the process type of all processes is shown.

For the w3wp.exe processes of those websites, I observe something strange:

1. Some of the website processes:

   - have process type: `Managed (.NET Core, .NET 5+), x64`
   - when selected, the "Attach to:" field shows `Automatic: Managed (.NET Core, .NET 5+) code`
2. some of the website processes:

   - have process type: `x64`
   - when selected, the "Attach to:" field shows `Automatic: Native code`

although, as far as I can see, I am using the same app pool and publish settings for all processes.

The processes which run on Windows Server 2019 IIS are all running as `x64`, whereas on my development machine, some run as `x64`, and some as `Managed (.NET Core, .NET 5+), x64` - and I have no clue why this difference, despite similar settings for all of them.

**Now the problem is** that debugging works only on processes of case 1. (type = `Managed (.NET Core, .NET 5+), x64`), but fails on all processes of case 2. (type = `x64`). For those, the symbols of relevant modules are not loaded with message `Native debugger skipped loading symbols for managed module.`.

Changing the attach-to code type from `automatic` to `Managed (.NET Core, .NET 5+)` does not work, attach fails with error message `Unable to attach to the process. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x92330062`.

**Added info:** application pools on both local and remote IIS are `No managed code`. Deployment settings are similar for all projects.

**Question:**
Why are some w3wp.exe processes shown as type `x64` and not as type  `Managed (.NET Core, .NET 5+), x64`? I need to change this to allow for debugging.

Comment: Please check your configuration information, and this link should help you: [Remote Debug ASP.NET Core on a Remote IIS Computer in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-computer?view=vs-2022).

Comment: @samwu Remote debugging works generally on that server and the config looks fine. Interestingly, I notice that also on my local development computer, I also see 2 other NET Core websites which show up as 'x64' rather than 'Managed (.NET Core, .NET 5+), x64' in the available processes list - and I can see no difference in configuration for those websites.

Comment: @samwu I rephrased the question so it is clearer that this is not a remote debugging issue.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.